# How to scan an object in java?

Tags: java, object

I am making exactly the same Java program that is in this link:

[Run-time Polymorphism in Java without "abstract"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709033/run-time-polymorphism-in-java-without-abstract)

But I am having problems in the Main Application.

In my problem I have to ask the user to enter which types does he want(Bicycle,MountainBike,RoadBike).

And then I add what type he chose to an array of 5 indexes.

How can I do that?

Please give me some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you look for answers from your users, but if it's buttons you do it with, you can just add the requested type of object, when a user press specific buttons.

But what you have to do, is make an `ArrayList<Bicycle>` and then just add the objects that extends Bicycle.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a factory method that returns an instance of a Bicycle:

For example:

```
public Bicycle createBicycle(String type) {
    if (type.equals("Bicycle")) {
        return new Bicycle(20, 10, 1);
    } else if (type.equals("MountainBike")) {
        return new MountainBike(20, 10, 5, "Dual");
    }
    //and so on..
}
```

And use it like this for example:

```
Bicycle[] bicycles = new Bicycle[5];
bicycle[0] = createBicycle("Bicycle");
```